# Многопоточность, ожидание окончания выполнения потоков

Tags: многопоточность, потоки-данных, java

Есть код для работы с потоками

```
ExecutorService threads = java.util.concurrent.Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        // создаём поток
        threads.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                  // какие-то инструкции потока
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Вопрос, внутри потока идёт:

1. пингование,
2. подключение к ssh серверу,
3. выполнение на нём нескольких команд.
   соответственно это дело занимает какое-то время, плюс иногда сервер может быть не доступен и поток соответственно выполняется дольше обычного.

Требуется:

1. запустить потоки,
2. подождать пока все потоки закончат выполнение,
3. продолжить выполнение основной программы.

Добавил:
  main()

```
ExecutorService threads = java.util.concurrent.Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        Future<String>[] tasks = new Future[servers.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < servers.size(); i++) {
            tasks[i] = threads.submit(new Thread_server(servers.get(i)));
        }

        while(checkThreads(tasks)) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        threads.shutdown();

        for (Future task : tasks) {
            try {
                System.out.println(task.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
```

функция checkThreads

```
private static boolean checkThreads(Future<String>[] tasks) {
    for (Future task : tasks) {

        if (!task.isDone()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

класс Thread_server

```
public class Thread_server implements Callable {

private Servers server = null;
private String result = null;

public Thread_server(Servers server) {
    this.server = server;
}

@Override
public String call() {

    try {
        boolean ping = false;
        String host = null;
        if (server.getEnabled() == 1) {
            if (server.getVpnIp() != 0) {
                ping = true;
                host = new Libs().intToIp(server.getVpnIp());
            } else {
                if (server.getGateIp()!= 0) {
                    ping = true;
                    host = new Libs().intToIp(server.getGateIp());
                }
            }
        }

        if (ping) {

            InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            boolean reachable = inet.isReachable(5000);
            if (reachable) {

                Ssh ssh = new Ssh(host);
                if (ssh.connect) {
                    result = server.getName() + " - на связи (" + host + ") =>" + ssh.exec("uptime");
                    result = result + " Date:" + ssh.exec("date");

                } else {
                    result = server.getName() + " - НЕ на связи";
                }
                ssh.sshDisconnect();

            } else {

                result = server.getName() + " - НЕ на связи";

            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return result;
    }

}

}
```

Проблема в том что если в 1вом варианте отвечали все серваки, то в последнем от не ответивших приходит null, а не должен.

Comment: Отлично. Что из этого у вас не получается? Что вы пробовали? Посмотрите на `Thread.start` и `Thread.join`.

Comment: Future f = threads.submit(...);   
так ?  
но потоков много

Comment: Ну так запомните их все в список, делов-то!

Comment: ещё вопрос, как бы ещё ответы потоков собрать в том же порядке?  
>у которого можно дождаться результата при помощи get.  
а как указать что из всего объекта потока является результатом?

Comment: ну, пробегите по списку ваших Future, скажите каждому get, получите список ответов. Заодно и дождётесь окончания всех.

---
Ну, передайте `Callable<T>`, а не просто `Runnable`. Получите на выход `Future<T>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

invokeAll запускает несколько потоков и ждет их завершения, поэтому можно писать что-то вроде этого:

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
List<Thread_server> tasks = new ArrayList<Thread_server>();

for (int i = 0; i < servers.size(); i++) {
    tasks.add(new Thread_server(servers.get(i))); // подготавливаем таски
}

List<Future<String>> answers = pool.invokeAll(tasks); // запустили, подождали и получили ответы
pool.shutdown(); // если не нужен
```

Comment: почему то на pool.invokeAll(tasks); не компилится

java: no suitable method found for invokeAll(java.util.List<ru.pack.Thread_server>)
    method java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.<T>invokeAll(java.util.Collection<? extends java.util.concurrent.Callable<T>>,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) is not applicable
      (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.<T>invokeAll(java.util.Collection<? extends java.util.concurrent.Callable<T>>) is not applicable

Comment: а нет, добавил <String> в Thread_server и скомпилилось  
    public class Thread_server implements Callable<String>

Answer (score 4):

Пишем что-то такое:

```
ExecutorService threads = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

List<Future<int>> tasks = new ArrayList<Future<int>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tasks.add(
        threads.submit(new Callable<int>() {
            @Override
            public int call() {
                int result = 0;
                // что-то активно делаем
                return result;
            }
        }));
}
```

Дожидаемся окончания и собираем результаты:

```
List<int> results = new ArrayList<int>();
for (Future<int> task : tasks)
    results.add(task.get());
```

Замените `int` на настоящий тип результата.

Comment: не всё работает, добавил в топике

Comment: А зачем вам код

    while(checkThreads(tasks)) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    threads.shutdown();

? Он явно не нужен.

---
А ещё вам нужен не `Callable`, а `Callable<String>`